# Do we need to Install chef inspec on prod servers?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

In our development environment , we created cookbooks and Chef inspec scripts to test the outcome.In our PROD servers, only chef client is present and CHEF inspec is not present.

Is it a good practice to install CHEF Inspec in all PROD servers(around 250+) so that we can run automated test?

Comment: Biggest selling point in my organization is that you do not need to install anything on machines you wish to query with inspec, you just need to be able to hit them with winrm or ssh from a machine that does have inspec installed on it.

Answer (score 2):

InSpec has no agent program so there is nothing to install, you only need to install it on the place running the tests (usually a CI server or compliance scanner).

Answer (score 1):

You can also run the tests from your dev machines using

```
inspec exec test/smoke/default -t winrm://username@hostname --password 'Password'
```

This is for Windows environment of course so need to adapt for ssh.